# Getting "PermissionDeniedError" when running the example program on Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, permissions

Sorry for my lack of knowledge, but I am trying to run the example on Tensorflow:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

feature_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column("x", shape=[1])]

estimator = tf.estimator.LinearRegressor(feature_columns=feature_columns)

x_train = np.array([1., 2., 3., 4.])
y_train = np.array([0., -1., -2., -3.])
x_eval = np.array([2., 5., 8., 1.])
y_eval = np.array([-1.01, -4.1, -7, 0.])
input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    {"x": x_train}, y_train, batch_size=4, num_epochs=None, shuffle=True)
train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    {"x": x_train}, y_train, batch_size=4, num_epochs=1000, shuffle=False)
eval_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    {"x": x_eval}, y_eval, batch_size=4, num_epochs=1000, shuffle=False)


estimator.train(input_fn=input_fn, steps=1000)

train_metrics = estimator.evaluate(input_fn=train_input_fn)
eval_metrics = estimator.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_fn)
print("train metrics: %r"% train_metrics)
print("eval metrics: %r"% eval_metrics)
```

I got the following error message:
PermissionDeniedError: Failed to delete a file: C:\Users\Jeff\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpgpmjek44\graph.pbtxt.tmpe31b9f4677cb426fbaef32dadeaf1a4d; Permission denied

I found the error comes from the line "estimator.train(input_fn=input_fn, steps=1000)". I tried to look at the folder and the file. They are granted full control already. This maybe a stupid question but what can possibly the cause and solution here. Thank you so much in advance!

UPDATE:

I ran it from the root and got the following:

> (C:\Users\Jeff\Anaconda3) C:\Users\Jeff>python test.py
>   WARNING:tensorflow:Using temporary folder as model directory:
>   C:\Users\Jeff\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp0yywjv30 2017-11-10
>   22:54:59.808636: I
>   C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:137]
>   Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not
>   compiled to use: AVX AVX2 2017-11-10 22:55:00.096842: I
>   C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1030]
>   Found device 0 with properties: name: GeForce GTX 1060 major: 6 minor:
>   1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.6705 pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 totalMemory:
>   6.00GiB freeMemory: 4.99GiB 2017-11-10 22:55:00.096927: I C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1120]
>   Creating TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0) -> (device: 0, name:
>   GeForce GTX 1060, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
>   2017-11-10 22:55:02.512317: E
>   C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_blas.cc:366]
>   failed to create cublas handle: CUBLAS_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED 2017-11-10
>   22:55:02.513461: E
>   C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_blas.cc:366]
>   failed to create cublas handle: CUBLAS_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED 2017-11-10
>   22:55:02.513601: E
>   C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_blas.cc:366]
>   failed to create cublas handle: CUBLAS_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED 2017-11-10
>   22:55:02.514975: E
>   C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_blas.cc:366]
>   failed to create cublas handle: CUBLAS_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED 2017-11-10
>   22:55:02.515067: W
>   C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\stream_executor\stream.cc:1901]
>   attempting to perform BLAS operation using StreamExecutor without BLAS
>   support Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Jeff\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 1323, in _do_call
>       return fn(*args)   File "C:\Users\Jeff\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 1302, in _run_fn
>       status, run_metadata)   File "C:\Users\Jeff\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py",
>   line 473, in **exit**
>       c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status)) tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Blas GEMV
>   launch failed:  m=1, n=4
>            [[Node: linear/linear_model/x/weighted_sum = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](linear/linear_model/x/Reshape,
>   linear/linear_model/x/weights)]]
>            [[Node: linear/gradients/linear/linear_model/x/weighted_sum_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1/_85
>   = _Recvclient_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0",
>   send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0",
>   send_device_incarnation=1,
>   tensor_name="edge_184_linear/gradients/linear/linear_model/x/weighted_sum_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1",
>   tensor_type=DT_FLOAT,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test.py", line 39, in
>   
>       estimator.train(input_fn=input_fn, steps=1000)   File "C:\Users\Jeff\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py",
>   line 302, in train
>       loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)   File "C:\Users\Jeff\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py",
>   line 783, in _train_model
>       _, loss = mon_sess.run([estimator_spec.train_op, estimator_spec.loss])   File
>   "C:\Users\Jeff\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py",
>   line 521, in run
>       run_metadata=run_metadata)   File "C:\Users\Jeff\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py",
>   line 892, in run
>       run_metadata=run_metadata)   File "C:\Users\Jeff\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py",
>   line 967, in run
>       raise six.reraise(*original_exc_info)   File "C:\Users\Jeff\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 693, in
>   reraise
>       raise value   File "C:\Users\Jeff\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py",
>   line 952, in run
>       return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Jeff\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py",
>   line 1024, in run
>       run_metadata=run_metadata)   File "C:\Users\Jeff\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py",
>   line 827, in run
>       return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Jeff\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 889, in run
>       run_metadata_ptr)   File "C:\Users\Jeff\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 1120, in _run
>       feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)   File "C:\Users\Jeff\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 1317, in _do_run
>       options, run_metadata)   File "C:\Users\Jeff\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 1336, in _do_call
>       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message) tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Blas GEMV
>   launch failed:  m=1, n=4
>            [[Node: linear/linear_model/x/weighted_sum = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](linear/linear_model/x/Reshape,
>   linear/linear_model/x/weights)]]
>            [[Node: linear/gradients/linear/linear_model/x/weighted_sum_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1/_85
>   = _Recvclient_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0",
>   send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0",
>   send_device_incarnation=1,
>   tensor_name="edge_184_linear/gradients/linear/linear_model/x/weighted_sum_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1",
>   tensor_type=DT_FLOAT,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]
>
> Caused by op 'linear/linear_model/x/weighted_sum', defined at:   File
>   "test.py", line 39, in 
>       estimator.train(input_fn=input_fn, steps=1000)   File "C:\Users\Jeff\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py",
>   line 302, in train
>       loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)   File "C:\Users\Jeff\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py",
>   line 711, in _train_model
>       features, labels, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.TRAIN, self.config)   File "C:\Users\Jeff\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py",
>   line 694, in _call_model_fn
>       model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)   File
>   "C:\Users\Jeff\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\canned\linear.py",
>   line 348, in _model_fn
>       config=config)   File "C:\Users\Jeff\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\canned\linear.py",
>   line 118, in _linear_model_fn
>       logits = logit_fn(features=features)   File "C:\Users\Jeff\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\canned\linear.py",
>   line 70, in linear_logit_fn
>       features=features, feature_columns=feature_columns, units=units)   File
>   "C:\Users\Jeff\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\feature_column\feature_column.py",
>   line 321, in linear_model
>       column, builder, units, weight_collections, trainable))   File "C:\Users\Jeff\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\feature_column\feature_column.py",
>   line 1376, in _create_dense_column_weighted_sum
>       return math_ops.matmul(tensor, weight, name='weighted_sum')   File "C:\Users\Jeff\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py",
>   line 1891, in matmul
>       a, b, transpose_a=transpose_a, transpose_b=transpose_b, name=name)   File
>   "C:\Users\Jeff\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_math_ops.py",
>   line 2436, in _mat_mul
>       name=name)   File "C:\Users\Jeff\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py",
>   line 787, in _apply_op_helper
>       op_def=op_def)   File "C:\Users\Jeff\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py",
>   line 2956, in create_op
>       op_def=op_def)   File "C:\Users\Jeff\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py",
>   line 1470, in **init**
>       self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access
>
> InternalError (see above for traceback): Blas GEMV launch failed: 
>   m=1, n=4
>            [[Node: linear/linear_model/x/weighted_sum = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](linear/linear_model/x/Reshape,
>   linear/linear_model/x/weights)]]
>            [[Node: linear/gradients/linear/linear_model/x/weighted_sum_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1/_85
>   = _Recvclient_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0",
>   send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0",
>   send_device_incarnation=1,
>   tensor_name="edge_184_linear/gradients/linear/linear_model/x/weighted_sum_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1",
>   tensor_type=DT_FLOAT,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]

Answer (score -2):

Its  PermissionDeniedError:
You should run this script from the root as i can see for now. 
Try it and update.